# GIS Dictionary/Glossary

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are lots of terms, abbreviations and commonly used phrases about GIS. Sometimes I don't decide which term or abbreviation i should use for explaning something.

Should we make a good glossary under this site? I know that there are tags and wikis but if there is only glossary for gis terms, it can be only referenced source for everyone.

So we can don't need to use Google, [ESRI Dictionary](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/Gisdictionary/browse), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/) or [GIS Glossary](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/GIS_Glossary).

Comment: Isn't that essentially what tags are for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My 2 cents:

Compiling and maintaining a glossary is a large undertaking. I'm not sure it's worth the effort when so many other tools, including those mentioned in the question, are already available.

A few clicks are required to open and search in one of those tools when needed. However, the same would be true for a glossary that was part of this site (similar to opening the FAQ when reading a question).

If StackExchange offered a pop-up type of glossary, similar to the pop-ups that appear when you mouse-over a tag, then the effort might be worthwhile since no additional clicks would be needed.